# How to choose Bulgarian split squats or front foot-elevated split squats?

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, gym, exercise-selection

Why would one want to do front foot-elevated split squats instead of Bulgarian split squats, or vice versa?

In terms of which muscles they provide greater stimulus to, whether they're more useful for strength or hypertrophy in different ways. I'm looking for a cross-analysis of the two movements so that I can choose which one I might want to include in my own program, based on how they may suit different goals.

Comment: As long as there is no answer I would simply do some sets of both and compare how my body feels like. No one can tell you whether you are missing some small muscles involved in a certain movement but you can feel it by trying the exercise

Answer (score 1):

Rear foot elevated is a more challenging movement (you need more balance) and can target the quads more (flexion on front leg and lengthening on the back leg).

Front foot elevated is a good variation for glute and hip focus, and requires less balance. It can be used to limit knee flexion on the front leg. Can be a good variation if you have long legs, lack quad or hip mobility or have some knee issue.